# Como encontrar uma string exata dentro de outra string em LUA?

Tags: string, lua

Dado os seguintes dados:

```
local products = {
  ["Abóbora-menina seco(a)"] = { originalName = "Dried Butternut Squash" },
  ["Abóbora-menina fermentado"] = { originalName = "Fermented Butternut Squash" },
  ["Hidromel de abóbora-menina"] = { originalName = "Butternut Squash Mead" },
  ["Vinagre de abóbora-menina"] = { originalName = "Butternut Squash Mead Vinegar" },
  ["Abóbora-menina em conserva"] = { originalName = "Pickled Butternut Squash" },
  ["Abóbora fermentado"] = { originalName = "Fermented Pumpkin" },
  ["Hidromel de abóbora"] = { originalName = "Pumpkin Mead" },
  ["Vinagre de abóbora"] = { originalName = "Pumpkin Mead Vinegar" },
  ["Abóbora em conserva"] = { originalName = "Pickled Pumpkin" },
}

local ingredient = "abóbora"
```

Como fazer com que o retorno da função seja apenas os produtos que contenham `abóbora` e não `abóbora-menina` ?

Tentativa atual:

```
function SimilarProductsTemplate(products, ingredient)
  local template = ""
  for productName, productData in pairs(products) do
    if string.match(string.lower(productName), string.lower(ingredient)) then
      template = template .. productName .. "\n"
    end
  end
  return template
end
```

Output atual:

```
Abóbora-menina seco(a)
Vinagre de abóbora-menina
Vinagre de abóbora
Abóbora em conserva
Abóbora fermentado
Abóbora-menina em conserva
Hidromel de abóbora
Hidromel de abóbora-menina
Abóbora-menina fermentado
```

Output esperado:

```
Vinagre de abóbora
Abóbora em conserva
Abóbora fermentado
Hidromel de abóbora
```

Resolução final encontrada caso alguém mais precise:

Como o valor utilizado no ingredient possui um `-` (abóbora-menina) o match anulava tudo após como ele então ele procurava tudo que não terminava com `menina`.

Usando % conseguimos deixar o `-` literal e o problema se resolve para o nome `abóbora-menina`:

```
    local ingredient = "Abóbora%-menina"

    function SimilarProductsTemplate(products, ingredient)
      local template = ""
      for productName, productData in pairs(products) do
        if string.match(string.lower(productName).." ", string.lower(ingredient) .. '%s') then
          template = template .. productName .. "\n"
        end
      end
      return template
    end
```

Comment: Não é só remover os `string.lower`? Dê uma [olhada](http://tpcg.io/_LXWFWS)

Comment: Output: Hidromel de abóbora-menina,
Vinagre de abóbora-menina,
Vinagre de abóbora,
Hidromel de abóbora

Comment: Entendi agora, teria que quebrar as palavras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quebrando o nome do produto em palavras, através da função `productName:gmatch("%S+")`, você pode comparar se no produto há aquele ingrediente ou não.

A função `gmatch("%S+")` faz um `split` das palavras buscando por espaços.

Veja:

```
local products = {
  ["Abóbora-menina seco(a)"] = { originalName = "Dried Butternut Squash" },
  ["Abóbora-menina fermentado"] = { originalName = "Fermented Butternut Squash" },
  ["Hidromel de abóbora-menina"] = { originalName = "Butternut Squash Mead" },
  ["Vinagre de abóbora-menina"] = { originalName = "Butternut Squash Mead Vinegar" },
  ["Abóbora-menina em conserva"] = { originalName = "Pickled Butternut Squash" },
  ["Abóbora fermentado"] = { originalName = "Fermented Pumpkin" },
  ["Hidromel de abóbora"] = { originalName = "Pumpkin Mead" },
  ["Vinagre de abóbora"] = { originalName = "Pumpkin Mead Vinegar" },
  ["Abóbora em conserva"] = { originalName = "Pickled Pumpkin" },
}

local ingredient = "abóbora"

function SimilarProductsTemplate(products, ingredient)
  local template = ""
  for productName, productData in pairs(products) do
    
    words = {}
    for word in productName:gmatch("%S+") do         
        if string.lower(ingredient) == string.lower(word) then
          template = template .. productName .. "\n"
        end
    end
  end
  return template
end


print(SimilarProductsTemplate(products, ingredient))
```

O output é esse:

```
Hidromel de abóbora
Vinagre de abóbora
Abóbora em conserva
Abóbora fermentado
```

Comment: Neste caso, se eu mudar o ingredient para `abóbora-menina` continua retornando apenas com `abóbora`, porque?

Comment: @AnaPaula, sua dúvida em si é sobre o `string.match`? Da pra resolver este caso com uma comparação simples. Ex: `string.lower(word) == string.lower(ingredient)`

Comment: Siim excelente! Cheguei em algo parecido, porem usando o match msm, orbigada pelos insights!

Comment: Vou confessar, demorei para dar o upvote. Mas hoje resolvi saber como funciona a [captura de padrões](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) e que [quebra de strings](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin) em LUA. O leitor tem que entender que Lua não usa regex e que LUA foi projetado para ser leve e incorporável o que implica que muitas ferramentas encontradas em outras linguagens não existem em LUA. Portanto essa abordagem faz bastante sentido.